# d3 force only display certain links and nodes on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js, force-layout

I've got a force directed layout set up in d3, but I'm trying to make it so that only certain links and nodes display, in accordance with a horizontal group of buttons I have set up.

Essentially, the force layout would display links and nodes based on whatever buttons are toggled on. For example, if I click on academia, federal, and commonwealth, only the links and nodes under those groups would display in my visualization. Does anyone know how I can set this up?

Here is a link to my code: https://plnkr.co/edit/QZ8chcsOj64oYJnIqz1J?p=preview

Here are my buttons (lines 27-64 in index.html):

```
    <div class="legend;" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px;">

    <div class="ngolegend item">
        <svg height="20" width="300">
            <circle cx="15" cy="12" r="4" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="orange" fill-opacity="0.6" />
            <text x="25" y="16" font-family="serif" font-size="12px">Non-Governmental Organizations</text>
        </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="academialegend item">
        <svg height="20" width="300">
            <circle cx="15" cy="12" r="4" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="steelblue" fill-opacity="0.6" />
            <text x="25" y="16" font-family="serif" font-size="12px">Academia</text>
        </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="commonwealthlegend item">
        <svg height="20" width="300">
            <circle cx="15" cy="12" r="4" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="green" fill-opacity="0.6" />
            <text x="25" y="16" font-family="serif" font-size="12px">Commonwealth</text>
        </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="federallegend item">
        <svg height="20" width="300">
            <circle cx="15" cy="12" r="4" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="red" fill-opacity="0.6" />
            <text x="25" y="16" font-family="serif" font-size="12px">Federal</text>
        </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="militarylegend item">
        <svg height="20" width="300">
            <circle cx="15" cy="12" r="4" stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="purple" fill-opacity="0.6" />
            <text x="25" y="16" font-family="serif" font-size="12px">Military</text>
        </svg>
    </div>

</div>
```

And I'm guessing the code I would need would go in here? (lines 207-209 in script.js):

```
$(".item").click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass("gray");
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extra information on these nodes and links by using `data-[name]` to distinguish different types of data, such as `data-type`.

```
 var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(json.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("data-type", function(d){
          return d.Sector; // add data attributes for later usage.
        })
        .attr("class","node") // better to give them class name
```

Then add filtering code like this in the dashboard toggle function:

```
$(".item").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("gray");
  var text = $(this).find("text").text()
  if($(this).hasClass("gray")){
     d3.selectAll(".node")
       .filter(function(d,i){
         return d3.select(this).attr("data-type") == text;
       })
       // filter nodes with the same type, and make it invisible
      .style("opacity",0)
 }else {
    d3.selectAll(".node")
     .filter(function(d,i){
     return d3.select(this).attr("data-type") == text;
    })
   .style("opacity",1)
 }
});
```

The method is similar for links, I suppose you can add the type info into the data source. And keep the name of the 'type' consistent while filtering('Commonwealth' V.S 'Commonwealth of Virginia'). Example plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Tpy1xvjQ4hw32uRI1gki?p=preview), click on 'Academia', 'Federal', 'Military' to see how it works for node (the other two types aren't working because of the naming consistency issue).

Update for question in comments:
To achieve the effect of only show information tab while clicking on children nodes, you can check the name of the parent node and compare it with the dashboard items:

```
 // collect the items in the dashboard panel
 var items = []; 
 $(".item").each(function(){
   items.push($(this).find("text").text())
 })
```

Then in the click event listener:

```
if($.inArray(d.name, items) !== -1){return}  
// check if this node is the parent node describe in dashboard panel
```

Example plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/2TLqAQAcMoKFeZKSd3ff?p=preview). Again, there is some data inconsistency just for the 'common wealth' type, should be 'common wealth of virgina'. (click on 'federal', 'academia', 'non-government organization' types to see how it turns out)

Comment: Awesome! I've got it working! Unfortunately, the titles for the nodes are darker now though. Do you know how I can get that problem fixed? Here is the update: https://plnkr.co/edit/QZ8chcsOj64oYJnIqz1J?p=preview

Comment: It looks good to me, the titles for the nodes are the same while toggling dashboard, can you please describe the problem in detail?

Comment: I managed to get it looking better now. The problem I'm having now is that I need to set up bounding boxes. The ability to remove some of the nodes, leaves a great deal of white space now, but this problem can be solved by setting up bounding boxes for my data-types. Do you know anything about how to do this? I've tried a good amount of research on d3 bounding boxes but haven't found an explanation that breaks it down the way I'd need to understand it.

Comment: Do you mean the range of the canvas for force layout should be responsive when you remove or add nodes? Would it be better to describe the details in another question perhaps?

Comment: Yes that is essentially what I'm looking for. And yes it seems like it might be right for a different question. Do you have any ideas on how I get set up my visualization so that if you click on the middle nodes, it does not trigger the dashboard to display though? Ideally, the dashboard would display only if you click on the outer nodes.

Comment: @JugalPatel I updated the answer with your following question. If that's what you need, accepting the answer would be great :)